# Form date from foreach loop through object

Tags: php, arrays, object, foreach

So I have an array of objects that looks like this:

```
credit_cards[[0] => {expiration_date: {year: "17", month: "04"}]
```

What I try to do is somethings like this:

```
$years = [];
$months = [];
$dates = [];
foreach ($clients->settings->credit_cards as $key => $value){
                        $years[] = $value->expiration_date->year;
                        $months[] = $value->expiration_date->month;
                    }
```

I need to loop through every credit card in that array and make an array `$dates` that should form a basic date by concatenating years and months. So in this case it should look like this: `$dates = ['2017-04']`. But I have no idea how to do this. Any help is welcomed and some explanation if you may so I can understand how to do this in the future.

Comment: Try using an `array_map`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add the dates with a minor amount of work.  create a parseable string that represents your **Month / Year**.  Then put it in [php's strtotime()](http://php.net/strtotime). That integer representing seconds since the epoch is the 2nd argument to format the **four digit date -dash- month** that you are looking for.

```
$years[] = $value->expiration_date->year;
$months[] = $value->expiration_date->month);
$my = $value->expiration_date->month.'/'.$value->expiration_date->year;
$dates[] = date('Y-m', strtotime($my));
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the concatenate operator: `.` ([More info here.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)) You can build a formatted date string and pass it to strtotime like WEBjuju's answer, or move directly to using the concatenation.

```
$years[] = $value->expiration_date->year;
$months[] = $value->expiration_date->month;
$dates[] = $value->expiration_date->year . '-' . $value->expiration_date->month;
```